# Is a job with a flaky employer worth pursuing?

Tags: applications

I applied for a position with a local company and on the day I applied I spoke with the employer twice. He seemed extremely excited about bringing me on board as soon as possible but explained that he would be busy and probably wouldn't contact me until Friday (July 26th) or that weekend.

On Thursday I decided to send an email to the employer with some of my updated work (that I wasn't initially able to provide when we first spoke). Friday comes, no contact. The weekend comes, no contact. I'm finding it hard to believe that he wouldn't of at least replied to my email, let alone called me when he said he would if he was still interested in hiring.

The job posting is still up (which I'm guessing means the position hasn't been filled) and I still have yet to receive any contact. Should I cross this job off my list or should I try and reach out to the employer?

I feel like if I even need to reach out to the employer (after they explained thoroughly that they would be contacting ME) that this job will be a nightmare from the get-go.

Comment: Just because they haven't contacted in a few days, this is enough to be a flake?  There could be a few reasons for this: Illness, death in the family, business being really busy, or a few other things.  That you see this as a nightmare so quickly makes me wonder if you could see this from another side?

Comment: They explicitly stated they would contact me and did not. I emailed them and received no reply.

Comment: 1) You wrote that they said they wouldn't contact you before July 26th. 2) Anyone can be a day or so late. You're reading too much into this.

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty routine.  Sometimes someone tells you they're in a hurry and then nothing happens for a couple of weeks.  They're probably putting out a fire.

Among the things that can happen is invisible third party involvement - I proposed that someone do the technical writing on a project I'm working on, and forwarded this to the client, and the client said, basically: 'we'll think about it when we get back from vacation'.  So I left someone hanging for weeks.  Actually not, I told him where things were, but that it was going to take time.

Often the attitude is - you don't work here yet, so we don't have to explain anything. It's just is what it is. Relax, keep looking, and if they're in a mood to commit they'll commit.